# AttributeError: Object: Environment <workspace> not found from ArcGIS 9.3 Geoprocessor?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-9.3, geoprocessing-service

This problem is occurring in ArcGIS Server 9.3, Python 2.5.2

I am exposing a typical python script as a geoprocessing service.  In this script, I frequently use the gp.ListFeatureClasses() method, which searches the current workspace as shown in snippet below.

```
import arcgisscripting
gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3)
gp.workspace = "C:/someworkspace/mygdb.gdb" 
featureClasses = gp.ListFeatureClasses()
```

In the initial portion of the script, everything works as expected.  But in later portions of the script, the service crashes when I call gp.workspace reporting the following error:

> `AttributeError: Object: Environment <workspace> not found`

My initial guess was that maybe the workspace was being set to a non-existent workspace or gdb, but I have been able to verify that the workspace is always infact valid.

Digging around a bit has shown that others have experienced the same problem.  However, none have been able to set the workspace AT ALL.

Has anyone ever experienced such issues?

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue, and only got around it by reassigning the location for the workspace everytime I wanted to list any featureclasses

Comment: Thanks for the response - but that is where I getting the error.  When I call gp.Workspace = 'C:/new_workspace' in mid-script I get the Object: Environment <workspace> not found error.

Comment: Try setting gp.Workspace = null before you reset it, or simply create a string reference to the datasets env location and 'prepend' it

Comment: One last thing to note, is how are you licensed?  Is it through a license server?  Can you post the whole script up?

Comment: The other thing I do, differently, is pass the environment in as a variable, so it might be acting differently?  I don't know, as it is flaky, but it seems to work

Comment: I am starting to think this is, and excuse the pun, an environment issue, as I cannot replicate it doing it the way you are, and mine works fine.  Some things I would do, is to bump any license server, reinstall possibly, your instance?


How are you running the script?  Can you run it in IDLE?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, just getting back to this one.  This script runs perfectly fine in the desktop environment.  I dont get the "Environment <workspace> not found" until I execute script as service.  I totally reinstalled AGIS 9.3 in a fresh VM environment today, and still facing same error. I am still very much baffled.

Comment: AH, I didn't realise you were in a VM env.